# How to solve run time error '9' subscript out of range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns in my Excel worksheet - Reference, Value and Date. The code goes through all given values and works perfectly but at the end I have run time error at `pReference = data_table2(i + 1, 1)`.

```
Set Sheet_data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup")
last_Row = Sheet_data.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Set data_table = Sheet_data.Range("A2:C" & last_Row)
data_table2 = data_table.Value2

' New Code for Excel Export
For i = 1 To (last_Row - 1)
    If isDeveloper() = True Then
        pReference = data_table2(i + 1, 1)
        pValue = data_table2(i + 1, 2)
        pdate = data_table2(i + 1, 3)
    End If
```

Comment: `For i = lbound(data_table2, 1) To ubound(data_table2, 1)` and remove the `+ 1`.

Comment: Thanks GSerg it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the values of last_Row.

If you have a region of values for eg. A1:C22, the last_row will be 23, but you assigning to data_table Range("A2:C" & last_row) so you are starting from the second row.

it will be always subscript out of range error on the end, coz on the last itteration assign i = 23, and the array len is 22, so you are out of range

change your for loop to for each loop, or do this this way

```
For i = 1 to UBound(data_table2)
    If isDeveloper() = True Then
        pReference = data_table2(i, 1)
        pValue = data_table2(i, 2)
        pdate = data_table2(i, 3)
    End If
```